# Calculate the amount of words from the alphabet $(A,B)$ that contains seven $A$ and four $B$.

Tags: combinatorics

As in title I am struggling to solve this problem. I tried to think about the total amount of words with $11$ letters by taking $2^{11}$ minus the amount of words that does not contain $4 A$ and $7 B$, but if I can do that, I can just calculate directly $4 A$ and $7 B$. I am pretty much blind here, can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: do you know what combinations are?

Comment: I am learning about that right now. There are some that I manage to do on my own, but like this one I can't figure it out. Been trying for a long amount of time now...

Comment: its literally 11 choose 7, or in math lingo, $11\choose7$

Comment: It might be a silly question but isn't this for unordered selections then? I thought for this problem you have to take the order that the letters come in consideration?

Comment: You are choosing the 4 positions to place the 4 As. It doesn't matter which A is placed where. hence combinations.

Comment: Oh okay, cause what I have heard is that this only applies for unordered and when I think about this, I thought the order of the letters is important. Thanks man

Comment: The order of the letters is important.  The order is determined by choosing which four of the eleven positions will be filled with $A$s.  The remaining positions must be filled with $B$s.